# Find opening names from fen online query

Tags: opening

I have the fen(arbitrary), I would like to get the completely opening names for the move list by passing the fen to the site. Are there any sites like this that are pretty exhaustive and free? It could simply return the last opening name as I could query it manually but this requires more work than I'd like to do.

Every site I have is some downloadable database or has an interface for searching through openings. I'd like something I could just get the names in json, html or some other text that correspond to the fen moves ordering. I'd rather not have to try and hack up some site to try and extract the info.

Comment: Do you mean FEN or PGN? PGN would be the normal form for a move list.

Comment: @kentdjb FEN, that is what I get from the code. I have the sequence of them. I guess I deally I like to give a fen and it return all matching openings for it. I can then do the intersection to find out which ones I want. Of course, being able to convert to pgn would also help.

Answer (score 3):

I appreciate that this is not a complete answer to your request but one potential solution would be to download and use a local copy of my free open source [pgn-extract](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/%7Edjb/pgn-extract/) program and use options along the following lines:

```
pgn-extract --fenpattern "r1bqkb1r/pppp1ppp/2n2n2/4p3/2P5/2N2N2/PP1PPPPP/R1BQKB1R w KQkq" eco.pgn
```

The program comes with the file [eco.pgn](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/%7Edjb/pgn-extract/eco.pgn) that contains ECO codes and opening names so the above outputs all the matches in `eco.pgn` for openings that reach the given FEN position, for instance:

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "????.??.??"]
[Round "?"]
[White "?"]
[Black "?"]
[Result "*"]
[ECO "A28"]
[Opening "English"]
[Variation "four knights, Romanishin variation"]

1. c4 e5 2. Nc3 Nc6 3. Nf3 Nf6 4. e3 Bb4 5. Qc2 Bxc3 *
```

along with another 9 possibilities.